# PHP: Display a state depending upon zipcode with varibles & isset

Tags: php, string, get, isset, zipcode

With the first line of code below I'm able to grab the last part of the URL.

The second line of code I'm able to print out / display the zipcode (which is the last part of the URL).

The third part is where my issue is... I'm trying to get the `$state` to display what State depending upon the zipcode.

I have Alaska as my example. my whole code includes all 50 states.

```
<?php $str = "https://www.mywebsite.com/depts/$_GET[zipcode]"; $zipcode = explode("/",$str);?>
<?php print end($zipcode); ?>
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['zipcode'])){$checkZip=$_GET['zipcode'];}

//Alaska 
if($checkZip<99950 && $checkZip>99501){$state='Alaska';} ?>
```

**For example:** on my website the first page I ask for their zipcode. I then take their zipcode and create a clean URL with .htaccess which then spits out the *https://www.mywebsite.com/depts/90210*

What I'm trying to do is to display the "State" on the second page depending upon the supplied zipcode from the first page.

Comment: `"my whole code includes all 50 states"` in what format? In a db? Text? The logic used `if($checkzip > X && $checkzip < Y)` will quickly become tiresome to write and possibly debug but your question remains fairly elusive/unclear. Please add a sample of the data and clarify the issue you have

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Thank you for your reply! after further testing my code with different approaches I got it to work by replacing `if(isset($_GET['zipcode'])){$checkZip=$_GET['zipcode'];}` with `$checkZip=end($zipcode);` and it worked perfectly!